# Strange Button Behavior

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My form has several textboxes and several buttons.  The textboxes are loaded with data by the load event.  If I make changes to the textboxes and then move the cursor over a button, the textboxes are suddenly loaded again with the original information.  I don't click a button.  I just move the mouse over one.  Why is this happening and how do I stop it?

Comment: Winforms, webforms or WPF? Can you post the relevant bits of code? Are you sure you have not registered an event handler for the mouseover/mouseout?

Comment: This is just a standard Windows form.  I was mistaken about the load event.  The textboxes are filled by the paint event.  I have checked the mouseover/mouseout events and there is nothing there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot happen by itself. I suggest you check all event-settings.

For instance, you could have, by accident, linked the **Load** event to the Button's **OnMouseEnter** or something like that.

---

#### After your comment:

You should absolutely ***not*** use the paint event to initialize things. The paint event will be called after **every** change in the Form.

So move that code to the Load event.